# How automatically to add spaces inbetween each character in a text string?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

Teachers I work with, enter four scores for a student’s assessment in a single cell, like this: `2113`, with no breaks or spaces.

How can I separate those characters so as to be able to create a chart of the four individual scores?

Comment: In order to create a chart wouldn't those 4 scores need to be in separate cells, rather than simply separated by spaces?

Answer (score 5):

You could split the cell's value into individual cells. Given that cell `A1` contains the number `2113`, put the following in cell `B1`:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE("" & A1, "(\d)", "$1,"), ",")
```

This should result in cells `B1:E1` containing each respective digit.

What the formula does is three things:

1. The expression `"" & A1` converts the input number `2113` to a
   string.
2. The `REGEXPREPLACE` replaces the input string `2113` with a
   comma-separated list of digits: `2,1,1,3,`.
3. Finally, the `SPLIT` function splits the comma-separated string into
   separate cells.

Now that you have each digit in a separate cell, you should be able to create a chart from the data.

If you still want to just add spaces between the digits, try

```
=REGEXREPLACE("" & A1, "(\d)", "$1 ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1); REPT("(.)"; LEN(A1)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), REPT("(.)", LEN(A1:A))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TO_TEXT(A1:A), REPT("(.)", LEN(A1:A)))), , 999^99)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The following custom formula will give the result that you want:

### Code

```
// empty string split
function emptySplit(cell) {
  return cell.toString().split('');
}

// same as above, but then joined afterwards, using a space (' ')
function spaceSplit(cell) {
  return cell.toString().split('').join(' ');
}
```

### Explained

The active cell in the spreadsheet is converted to a string (therefore it will work for strings and numbers), and the split method will separate the string using an empty string `('')`.

Add the little piece of code under Tools>Script editor. Press the save button and you can use your custom formula !!

The `SPLIT` function in Google Spreadsheets doesn't allow for empty strings to be used as delimiter.

### Usage

```
=emptySplit(A1)
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: [split with empty string as delimiter](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGZCQjFxVUhrMzFXUG5iUnBuZTRVcWc&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Another option (more mathematical rather than text) for splitting a four digit number in A1 into four separate cells is in B1 and copied across:

```
=left(mod($A1,10^(6-column())))
```

(Assumes no `0` scores!)

Answer (score 0):

The topmost answer's for REGEXREPLACE no longer works in current version of Sheets. 
Here's what worked for me:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2;"(\d)"; "$1 ")
```